# Computing custom function on numpy array results in UnpicklingError: NEWOBJ class argument has NULL tp_new

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, scipy, pyspark

Very strange problem I am running into where using spicy.spacial distance matrix computation works fine, but using a custom function for distance matrix results in a Spark error.

My data looks like this:

```
33.848366,-84.3733852,A,1234
33.848237299999994,-84.37318470000001,A,1234
33.8488057,-84.3731556,A,1234
33.847644200000005,-84.3727751,A,1234
33.84840429999999,-84.3732269,A,1234
33.849072899999996,-84.37342070000001,A,1234
33.8428191,-84.38306340000001,A,1234
33.842778499999994,-84.3830113,A,1234
33.8394582,-84.3770177,A,1234
33.847117299999994,-84.365351,A,1234
```

My fully reproducible code looks like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

# This function taken from another StackOverflow post (modified radius only)
def distHaversine(pos1, pos2, r = 6378137):
    pos1 = pos1 * np.pi / 180
    pos2 = pos2 * np.pi / 180
    cos_lat1 = np.cos(pos1[..., 0])
    cos_lat2 = np.cos(pos2[..., 0])
    cos_lat_d = np.cos(pos1[..., 0] - pos2[..., 0])
    cos_lon_d = np.cos(pos1[..., 1] - pos2[..., 1])
    return r * np.arccos(cos_lat_d - cos_lat1 * cos_lat2 * (1 - cos_lon_d))

def myFunc(x):
    points = pd.DataFrame(list(x[1]))
    points.columns = ['lat', 'lon']
    ## PROBLEM LINE: UNCOMMENTING THIS LINE AND COMMENT BELOW TWO RESULTS IN THE ERROR ##
    # pointsDistMatrix = distHaversine(np.array(points)[:, None], np.array(points))
    pointsDistMatrix = pdist(points)
    pointsDistMatrix = squareform(pointsDistMatrix)
    db = DBSCAN(eps = 75, min_samples = 3, metric = 'precomputed',
                algorithm = 'kd_tree').fit(pointsDistMatrix)
    points['cluster'] = db.labels_
    return ((x[0], [tuple(x) for x in points.values]))

textFile = sc.textFile('df.csv')
processedGeoData = textFile \
                   .map(lambda x: x.split(',')) \
                   .map(lambda x: ((str(x[3]), str(x[2])),
                                        (float(x[0]), float(x[1])))) \
                   .groupByKey() \
                   .sortByKey(False) \
                   .map(myFunc)

processedGeoData.collect()
```

Error I get is this:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 50.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 50.0 (TID 70, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.5.2/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.5.2/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.5.2/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
UnpicklingError: NEWOBJ class argument has NULL tp_new
```

Any idea what is going on? Why a custom matrix does not work, but scipy.spatial one works?

Here are the versions of different packages I am using:

```
Python 2.7.10
numpy==1.9.2
pandas==0.16.0rc1-22-g96aa9cb
scikit-learn==0.15.2
scipy==0.15.1
pyspark=1.5.2
```

Comment: It works fine when I use the same exact call with a 'precomputed' option using `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` (basically euclidean distance). Commenting that one line and uncommenting the other two lines causes it to run fine. If problem is with DBSCAN call, not sure why that would be the case. Is there some package version differences?

Comment: BTW - I did not get that ValueError in my case. Get this UnpickingError instead.

Comment: Can you include packages and Python versions?

Comment: Edited question and added at the end. Thanks!

Comment: This is quite out of data. Could you try updating?

Comment: Updated all packages and am now using Anaconda. Now, I get same kd_tree error. I removed that option from the `DBSCAN` call and ran it. Works fine with `pdist` while it produces `TypeError: can't pickle ellipsis objects` with the call to `distHaversine` instead of `pdist`.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work create a module `haversine.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def distHaversine(pos1, pos2, r = 6378137):
    pos1 = pos1 * np.pi / 180
    pos2 = pos2 * np.pi / 180
    cos_lat1 = np.cos(pos1[..., 0])
    cos_lat2 = np.cos(pos2[..., 0])
    cos_lat_d = np.cos(pos1[..., 0] - pos2[..., 0])
    cos_lon_d = np.cos(pos1[..., 1] - pos2[..., 1])
    return r * np.arccos(cos_lat_d - cos_lat1 * cos_lat2 * (1 - cos_lon_d))
```

and distribute it (`--py-files` / `sc.addPyFile`). Next import `distHaversine`

```
>>> from haversine import distHaversine
```

and you're fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the assist. It really helped me narrow the problem down. See below for what worked without splitting into separate file.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't like answering my own question, but for some strange reason others hit this same problem, I am hoping it can be helpful.

I re-wrote the above function to not use the 'ellipsis' operator to index into the array as follows:

```
def distHaversine(pos1, pos2, r = 6378137):
    pos1 = pos1 * np.pi / 180
    pos2 = pos2 * np.pi / 180
    cos_lat1 = np.cos(pos1[:, :, 0])
    cos_lat2 = np.cos(pos2[:, 0])
    cos_lat_d = np.cos(pos1[:, :, 0] - pos2[:, 0])
    cos_lon_d = np.cos(pos1[:, :, 1] - pos2[:, 1])
    return r * np.arccos(cos_lat_d - cos_lat1 * cos_lat2 * (1 - cos_lon_d))
```

Everything works fine after this change.

It seems like the ellipsis operator for some God unknown reason is interfering with the Spark serialization layer? No idea what is going on under the hood as I am not even returning the return value of the function to Spark. A totally different list of tuples from a cluster labeled pandas data frame.